# Nativescript ListView

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Can i add a ListView inside a Layout ?

I have this View:

```
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var array = new observableArray.ObservableArray();
    array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
    array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
    array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
    array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
    array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
    array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
    page.bindingContext = vmModule.mainViewModel, {"myItems": array};
};

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

And this template:

```
<GridLayout>
<TabView>
    <TabView.items>
        <TabViewItem title="Nearest Wifi">
            <TabViewItem.view>
                <GridLayout>
                     <ListView items="{{ myItems }}">
                        <ListView.itemTemplate>
                            <GridLayout columns="*,*" rows="2">
                               <Label col="0" row="0" text="{{ city || 'Downloading...' }}" textWrap="true" class="title" />
                               <Label col="1" row="0" text="{{ distance || 'Downloading...' }}" textWrap="true" class="title" />
                               <Label col="0" row="1" colspan="2" text="Votes: {{nr_votes | 0 }}"/>
                            </GridLayout>
                        </ListView.itemTemplate>
                     </ListView>
                </GridLayout>
            </TabViewItem.view>
        </TabViewItem>
```

...

I try to make it work for 3 hours .. any help would be apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the 'observableArray' module included in the .js file?            var observableArray = require("data/observable-array");

Comment: If I undertood right, you want to display a list of cities and in each row, display the city's name, distance and votes in three separated columns, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works well, I believe it's what you're after:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">

  <ActionBar title="Cities - WIFI" />

  <TabView>
    <TabView.items>
        <TabViewItem title="Nearest Wifi">
            <TabViewItem.view>
                <ListView items="{{ cities }}">
                    <ListView.itemTemplate>
                        <GridLayout columns="*,*,*" rows="*,*">
                            <Label col="0" row="0" text="City"/>
                            <Label col="1" row="0" text="Distance" />
                            <Label col="2" row="0" text="Votes" />

                            <Label col="0" row="1" text="{{city}}" />
                            <Label col="1" row="1" text="{{distance}}" />
                            <Label col="2" row="1" text="{{votes}}" />
                        </GridLayout>
                    </ListView.itemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </TabViewItem.view>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView.items>
  </TabView>
</Page>
```

Javascript:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;

var pageData = new Observable({
    cities: new ObservableArray([
        {city:"Madrid", distance:"0.2km",votes:"0"},
        {city:"Madrid", distance:"0.2km",votes:"0"},
        {city:"Madrid", distance:"0.2km",votes:"0"}
    ])
})
```

Comment: you cannot iterate data in a for loop with this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way if you want to iterate the data.
You can put array.push lines into for loop or wherever you want.

XML:

```
 <ListView items="{{ cities }}">
                <ListView.itemTemplate>
                    <GridLayout columns="*,*,*" rows="*,*">
                        <Label col="0" row="0" text="City"/>
                        <Label col="1" row="0" text="Distance" />
                        <Label col="2" row="0" text="Votes" />

                        <Label col="0" row="1" text="{{city}}" />
                        <Label col="1" row="1" text="{{distance}}" />
                        <Label col="2" row="1" text="{{votes}}" />
                    </GridLayout>
                </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

JS:

```
var array = new ObservableArray();

array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});
array.push({"city":"Madrid","distance":"0.2km","votes":"0"});

var pageData = new Observable({cities: array});

page.bindingContext = pageData;
```